# Live function not working in dynamic row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table, which contains a CheckBox and 2 columns. When clicking upon the CheckBox, I changed the row to color **Black** and change the  name of `<input type="hidden" name=old` to `<input type="hidden" name=new` then when unchecked, it changes the row back to normal. It is working only when in static.

**PROBLEM**: But when I add dynamic rows then click the Checkbox. Nothing happens. I used `live` function already. But still doesnt work.

Here is the working code for the static table:

For the `jquery` part:

```
$(".blackH").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","#CCC");
        $("input[name='old\\["+ $(this).data("old") +"\\]']").attr("name","new[" + $(this).data("old") + "]");
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","#FFF");
        $("input[name='new\\["+ $(this).data("old") +"\\]']").attr("name","old[" + $(this).data("old") + "]");
    }
});
```

`Live` function that I used but Not Working:

```
$(".blackH").click(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","#CCC");
    $("input[name='old\\["+ $(this).data("old") +"\\]']").attr("name","new[" + $(this).data("old") + "]");       
}
else{
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","#FFF");
    $("input[name='new\\["+ $(this).data("old") +"\\]']").attr("name","old[" + $(this).data("old") + "]");
}
});
```

For the `html` part:

```
        <tr class="trhighlight tagReflect {{tag_cnt}}" data-tagno="{{tag_cnt}}">
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="" class="del_chk blackH" data-savetag="{{tag_cnt}}"></td>
            <td style="width:70%;">DUMMY_DATA_1</td>
            <td class="" style="display: none;">DUMMY_DATA_2</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="old[{{tag_cnt}}]" value="">
        </tr>
```

Hope someone would help. Thanks.

Comment: What jquery version you are using ? any console error?

Comment: its version is 1.8.23 sir, and no console error.

Comment: `$('.trhighlight').on('click', '.blackH', function() { ... })`

Comment: Above jquery 1.7 , live() is  Deprecated

Comment: @TamilSelvan, yes but the weird part is its working in my other tables.

Comment: @adeneo it says `on is not a function`

Comment: Then your jQuery version is too old ?

Comment: then what live function to be used?

Comment: @Superman [`on` is present in 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, I'm not aware of there being a version 1.8.23 of jquery. Are you sure about your jQuery version?

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with the demo environment [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLJP4/), but I'm running jQuery 1.8.3. I'd suggest a more elegant approach like...

```
$(function() {
    $("tr .blackH").live("click", function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.checked ? "#ccc" : "");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `live` is deprecated and shouldn't be used in new code. [`on` is available since 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/)